# What counts as an armored or mechanical target?

Tags: saints-row-iv

The Quickshot Pistol has an 'Armor Piercing Ammo' upgrade that is described in-game as: "*Bullets do extra damage to armored and mechanical targets*".

[image]

**What counts as an armored or mechanical target?** Are vehicles, aircraft, [structures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zyXS.jpg) (like the ones you destroy in missions), Murderbots or Wardens considered armored or mechanical for the purposes of the Quickshot Pistol's 'Armor Piercing Ammo' upgrade?

Answer (score -1):

Murderbots count as mechanical, and you can shoot through the shields some Zin carry.

Comment: Do you also know if vehicles, aircraft, structures (like the ones you destroy in missions), or Wardens count as mechanical / armored too?

Comment: and why are you shooting vehicle with this little gun when you have black hole gun -_-